# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'member_name'

Tags: php, offset

i'm having this error in the error_log:

> [03-Jun-2015 12:22:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset
> 'member_name' in
> /home/admin/web/sof2.org/public_html/modules/Projects/public/PJIndex.php
> on line 84
>
> [03-Jun-2015 12:22:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string
> offset 'member_name' in
> /home/admin/web/sof2.org/public_html/modules/Projects/public/PJIndex.php
> on line 87

code is:

```
while(list($member_id, $position_id) = $db->sql_fetchrow($memberresult)) {
      $member = pjmember_info($member_id);
      foreach ($member as $member_loop) {
            $user_color = $db->sql_fetchrow($db->sql_query("SELECT `user_color_gc` FROM `" . $user_prefix . "_users` WHERE `username` = '".$member_loop['member_name']."'
                        "));
                        
            echo "- <span style=\'COLOR: #".$user_color['user_color_gc']."\'><strong>".$member_loop['member_name']."</strong></span>";
            echo "<br />";
        }
}
```

PHP Version 5.4.40

thank you!

Comment: Post the array structure of `$member`

Comment: What is in `$member`?

Comment: i think is this: $member = pjmember_info($member_id);

Comment: it state that your array `$member` have no index with name `member_name` . So either check it yourself or put your array here  get proper solution. thanks.

Comment: sorry but i don't know what i have to post here :(

Comment: after $member do this: `var_dump($member);` and post your result; BTW:  i think it wont be an array, bec your error msg already says illegal string offset!

Comment: i got it now.. result is this (not sure) array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "6" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(3) "Teo" ["member_name"]=> string(3) "Teo" [2]=> string(14) "obteo@live.com" ["member_email"]=> string(14) "obteo@live.com" }